# How to find a request from cron job in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, cron

I have a servlet running on GAE and I have a cron job that hits this servlet once in a while. Is there a way to differentiate the request coming from outside and from cron job so that I can do different action based on where the request is coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the request is coming from a Cron Service then it has a special [HTTP header](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron):

```
X-AppEngine-Cron: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...But this header can be faked right? Is there a fool proof way of checking if the request is from cron service? For now i am planning to check if the Remote Host is 0.1.0.1 and host http header is same as my domain name...Do you think this will work?

Comment: @PrabhuSwaminathan yes.. but if you read carefully the link then you will be able to restrict access to administrator accounts only.. and you are pretty much safe.. your question was to find out how.. how to prevent external access to these urls is another thing

Comment: The X-AppEngine-Cron header can only be faked by an admin of the App (allowed for testing purposes).